# Get correct value in dropdown according to model (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have dropdown with numbers populated from 1 to 10

Here is html of it

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label>{{l("RoomNumber")}}</label>
                        <p-dropdown [disabled] = "!roomNumbers.length"  [options]="roomNumbers" autoWidth="false"  [style]="{'width':'100%'}" name="numberRoom" [autoWidth]="true" [(ngModel)]="room.roomNumber"></p-dropdown>
                </div>
```

Here is how I populate it

```
getRoomNumber(): void {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        this.roomNumbers.push({label: i.toString(), value: i});
    }
}
```

When I save it to DB I get for example 2.

But in edit, I need to populate a dropdown with those numbers and select number saved in DB in this dropdown.

How I can do this?

Comment: You need to insert new numbers from db to dropdown?

Comment: I need to select number in dropdown, according to number from db@Qellson

Comment: You need to assign the db data to the room variable and you could try to change ngModel in html to [(ngModel)]="room"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using primeng.

To select the number of your room you have to change the value of the `ngModel`. In your scenario would be something like `this.room.roomNumber = id;` where id is the number you want.

**You have a live example of your code here:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-stack-55644995-dropdown?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts